# UIwebview loading slow in iOS 8 except English language

Tags: ios, objective-c, html, uiwebview

I am using UIWebView to load the embedded HTML.

English contains 800KB file size and other non english (Tamil, Hindi, Arabic) language contains 1.5MB content size. English will load faster to the UIWebView, it will take max 8 to 10seconds to load full file content to the web view, whereas non english takes min 25 to 30 seconds.

Is it possible to load the non english language to the UIWebview faster like english languages.

We have used these code to speed up in native.

```
   self.contentWebview.opaque=NO;
    self.contentWebview.scrollView.decelerationRate = UIScrollViewDecelerationRateNormal;
```

Comment: Are you downloading any fonts from net in regional HTMLs ?

Comment: no... for non english i am applying system fonts.. @GoodSp33d